# Is it possible to add existing ADFv2 activities to IF Condition activity as True & False activities?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Say I have a pipeline and there are already two activities in the pipeline as act-A and act-B. Now I add a new activity which is 'IF Condition' activity. Normally I always have to create 'new' activities to be added to IF Condition activity as True & False activities. How can I select existing activities act-A and act-B as true and false activities for the IF Condition activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like cutting and pasting of existing activity works , though the UI doesn't explicitly allows this.